# Basic number theory inequality?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I see that $$\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots(n-d)}{(d+1)!}\leq n^d(n-1)$$ holds for $n\geq 1$ and $d\geq 2$?

Comment: Is the left hand side just $\binom{n}{d+1}$?

Comment: Is $n^d+1$ supposed to be $n^{d+1}$?

Comment: As stated, it is wrong (the LHS is a polynomial in the $n$ variable with degree $d+1$, the RHS with degree $d$), and if in the RHS we replace $d$ with $d+1$ it becomes trivial.

Comment: A closely related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2570098/prove-that-sum-i-0d-n-choose-i-leq-nd-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide both sides by $n(n-1)$. Now the left-hand side is the product of $d-1$ numbers, all of them smaller than $n$, divided by $(d+1)!$. The right-hand side is the product of $d-1$ copies of $n$.

Comment: I fixed the mistake @Arthur

Comment: @CRYPTONEWBIE I edited my answer. It ought to apply to your updated question now.

Answer (score 0):

It's false, as stated. For a given $d$, the LHS is asymptotic to $n^{d+1}/(d+1)!$ and the RHS to $n^d$ and $n^{d+1}/(d+1)!$ will dominate $n^d$ for large $n$.

Are you sure you have the problem correctly?

---

Response to amended version.

If $d<n$ then $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-d)\le n(n-1)n\cdots n=n^d(n-1)$.
If $d\ge n$ then $n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-d)=0\le n^d(n-1)$.
In both cases, $n(n-1)\cdots(n-d)\ge0$ so that
$$\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-d)}{(d+1)!}\le n(n-1)\cdots(n-d)
\le n^d(n-1).$$

Comment: It seems to me that the LHS is $n^d\cdot n/(d+1)!$. That looks like it's dominated by $n^d$ for large $d$. I would rather look at small $d$.

Comment: Maybe the RHS is $n^{d+1}$?

Comment: When $d=2$ the LHS is $n^3/6-n^2/2+n/3$. That is usually bigger than $n^2+1$. @Arthur

Comment: I agree that the inequality, as stated, is not always true. But back when your answer said "for large $d$", it was wrong. That is what I meant by my previous comment. I retracted my downvote after you corrected it.

Comment: I fixed the mistake, sorry @LordSharktheUnknown

Answer (score 0):

The given inequality

$$\forall_{n\ge 1}\forall_{d\ge 1}\ \ \frac{\prod_{c=0}^d(n-c)}{(d+1)!}\ \le\ n^d\cdot(n-1) $$

is way weaker than necessary. This inequality follows easily from each one of the following:

$$ \forall_{n\ge 1}\forall_{d\ge 1}\quad \prod_{c=0}^d(n-c)
      \,\ \le\,\ n\cdot(n-1)^d $$

or (a little bit *more interesting*!)

$$\forall_{n\,\ge\,d\,\ge\, 1}\quad\frac{\prod_{c=0}^d(n-c)}{(d+1)!}\,\ \le\,\ (n-d)^{d+1} $$